# Issue with displaying html-tag Legend after Chrome update

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

HTML-Tag Legend with CSS-style {overiflow:hidden} disapiared after Chome/Edge update to v87.
Why?

[image: Before Update (Chrome/Edge v86)]
[image: After Update (Chrome/Edge v87)]

```css
fieldset {
    overflow: hidden;
}
legend {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        Test
    </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: ?? `background: 1px solid red;` should'nt be `border: 1px solid red;` ?

Comment: There is definitely a difference in behaviour between v86 and v87 (I just updated to test). You can resolve the issue in your specific example by removing `position: relative`.

Comment: G-Cyrillus, thank you, I fixed the typo. But it is not important for the main issue.

Comment: Looks like chromium issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151295